# Upper Bound for $\int_0^1 \exp(bx^{2a})\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals, exponential-function, upper-lower-bounds

I want to proof that
$$\int_0^1 \exp(bx^{2a})\mathrm dx=\mathcal O(b^{1-2a}\exp(2b^a)).$$
I already found the similar bound ($a<1/2$), maybe I could use this by substitution:
\begin{align}
\int_1^m \exp \left(2 t^{2 a}\right) d t =\int_1^m\left(4 a t^{2 a-1} \exp \left(2 t^{2 a}\right)\right) \frac{d t}{4 a t^{2 a-1}} \\
\leqslant\int_1^m\left(4 a t^{2 a-1} \exp \left(2 t^{2 a}\right)\right) \frac{d t}{4 a m^{2 a-1}} \leqslant \frac{m^{1-2 a}}{4 a} \exp \left(2 m^{2 a}\right)
\end{align}
but I don't understand the last bound, i.e
$$\int_1^m\left(4 a t^{2 a-1} \exp \left(2 t^{2 a}\right)\right)d t\le \exp \left(2 m^{2 a}\right).$$

Thanks

Comment: There is a missing $2$ probably.

Answer (score 1):

Use $2a < 1$ to have that $t^{2a - 1} \le 1$ and $t \le m$ to have $\exp\left({2t^2}\right) \le \exp \left(2m^2\right)$. You will have the inequality you are looking for.

Comment: So we have the interim step $\int_1^m4 a t^{2 a-1} \exp \left(2 t^{2 a}\right)d t\le\int_1^m4 a \exp \left(2 t^{2 a}\right)d t$. Why is the $4a$ needed for the last bound?